# How to monitor/profile a running .net assembly

Tags: .net, profile, .net-assembly, probe

We have a .net based windows service thats always running. I would like to make a .net win application that will probe this running .net process and tell me which method is currently executing.

I have the source code available for the .net windows service which I like to monitor. However I'm not allowed to make any changes in existing source code and insert any checkpoints/logging entries.

Ants profiler is something that does similar thing. But I dont want any performance/memory profiling. I just like to know is there any way in .Net C#, so that I can probe a running .net process and find which method is currently executing.

Comment: See [Sam's tool](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2009/11/11/Diagnosing+runaway+CPU+in+a+Net+production+application) - we us this frequently